# Comprobar que un campo de un array no está vacío en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, twig

Si tengo un array como este en y necesito acceder al campo `a` de cada campo con javascript, como debo hacerlo?
Necesito comprobar si alguno de ellos está vacío, realmente el array está en twig, pero lo pongo así porque no sé como se representa lo mismo en twig, ya que lo paso desde un php

```
 $arr = array (
      'campo1' => array(
         'a' => 'b',
      ),
      'campo2' => array(
         'a' => 'c',
      ),
      'campo3' => array(
         'a' => 'd',
      ),
      'campo4' => array(
         'a' => 'e',
      ),
    );
```

Lo que he intentado es lo siguiente

```
var arr = {{ arr|json_encode() }};
for (a in arr)
{
  if (arr[a] != '' && arr[a] != null)
  {
    alert('algo');
  }
}
```

Pero ese `alert` nunca se produce

Comment: ¿Un array o un objeto?

Comment: Es correcta la pregunta de Pablo, en JavaScript no existen "arrays asociativas", esto ya es un objeto como tal.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es que cuando itereras en tu `for in` traes contigo todos los campos haciendo que `arr[a] = {a : "b"}`, por ejemplo. Lo que necesitas entonces es acceder a tu propiedad a, entonces seria `arr[a].a = "b"`. Quedando de esta forma:

```js
var arr =  {"campo1":{"a":"b"},"campo2":{"a":"c"},"campo3":{"a":"d"},"campo4":{"a":"e"}};

for(a in arr) {
  if (arr[a].a !== '' && arr[a].a !== null) {
    console.log('El valor de a es ' + arr[a].a);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución muy sencilla y rápida es simplemente comprobar el elemento como tal que intentas validar, sin comparadores, actualmente estás haciendo una comparación contra el "objeto" completo, no contra en valor de "a":

```js
var arr = {"campo1":{"a":"b"},"campo2":{"a":"c"},"campo3":{"a":"d"},"campo4":{"a":"e"},"campo5":{"a":""},"campo6":{}};

for (a in arr)
{
  if (arr[a].a)
  {
    console.log('a en', a, 'no está vacío')
  }
}
```

Seguramente hay soluciones más completas, pero esta funciona en la mayoría de casos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo siguiente sí funciona:

```js
var arr = {"campo1":{"a":"b"},"campo2":{"a":"c"},"campo3":{"a":"d"},"campo4":{"a":"e"}};

for (a in arr)
{
  if (arr[a] != '' && arr[a] != null)
  {
    console.log(a,'no está vacío');
  }
}
```

Pero debes examinar el valor que se está asignando a `arr` (mirando el código de tu HTML) puesto que Twig puede estar escapando las comillas y escribiendo:

```
  var arr = {&quot;campo1&quot;:{&quot;a&quot;:&quot;b&quot;},&quot;campo2&quot;:{&quot;a&quot;:&quot;c&quot;},&quot;campo3&quot;:{&quot;a&quot;:&quot;d&quot;},&quot;campo4&quot;:{&quot;a&quot;:&quot;e&quot;}};
```

Para evitar eso, debes decirle a Twig que imprima la salida de `json_encode` sin escapar:

```
var arr = {{ arr|json_encode|raw }};
```